# Input controls overriding hidden table formula

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

I have a report I'm working on, where I have a series of tables attached to each other representing 18 months of our business year. Each table is being hidden if an input control of `Months` does not have the particular months listed, so only the most currently relevant months can be shown at a time.

The `Month` variable data isn't linked to any of the underlying data in any way.

I have another detail variable used as an input control, which represents staff associated with the row object. They're defined in a separate Excel document and merged with a dimension.

Using the `Months` input control by itself is great, as it hides the tables, but any time I use the other input control to filter rows by staff, every single table becomes visible again.

Each table, starting from April and extending into September of the next year has a similar formula, so I can select one or many of them. I tried using a date variable actually tied on the data, but it was breaking the cumulative nature of the data.

The formula used to hide the table:

```
=Pos(ReportFilter([Variables].[Months]); "01 - April Early Engagement") = 0
```

What would be causing this? How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: Could you add the formula(s) that you used to conditionally hide your tables?

Comment: Yes. I tried adding an image but didn't have enough rep to do so. I'll edit the original ;ost.

Comment: I'd create a section on the date dimension (tied to the data, not the *independent* `[Months]` dimension), which would automatically hide the table within the section if you'd deselect it from the input control. As for the issue with the *cumulative nature* you specified; I think that you could solve this by using calculation contexts.

Comment: I do not have the ability to create custom SQL or modify the underlying business objects. That is required for calculation contexts, isn't it?

Comment: Calculation contexts are defined in Webi. Please read the manual *Using functions, formulas and calculations in Web Intelligence*, chapter 4. This details what calculation contexts are and what they can be used for. There is no need to modify anything else than the formulas/variables you're using in your document.

Comment: Can you explain the implementation of the calculation context? Because I've tried using these already to help me achieve what I'm looking for but if I'm using month information tied to the data it cannot have multiple groupings and thus keeps filtering down. What I really need is the input control for logical display purposes and not actual filtering purposes. If I select just December, I want to see the values for all of December plus everything prior, not just the values unique to the month of December.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Setup

I created a report based on your specifications:

- 2 data providers: 1 dummy with just the months, 1 with actual data (in my case a set of dates and amounts
- One input control based on the dummy data providers with the months
- Another input control based on an object from the other data provider (in my case based on the year of the date object)
- 3 tables, each with a formula to conditionally hide them based on the dummy months

### Remarks

- Both input controls have their dependency set on the report, not the
  individual tables.
- The formula to hide the tables is: `=Pos(ReportFilter([Col1]); "Apr") = 0 Or Length(ReportFilter([Col1])) = 0`

### Proof

*April and August, only 2014*
[image: April and August, only 2014]

*April and August, only 2015*
[image: April and August, only 2015]

*April and December, only 2015*
[image: April and December, only 2015]

Comment: I notice your Amounts are the same for each month. If your April, August and December month Amounts only included values through to the end of each respective month as well as the sum of all values from every month prior, if you just selected December would December still include every value from the prior months?

Comment: The data in the tables is independent of the filter on months (I copied the same table 3 times and then added the formula to show/hide it). So basically, you could put whatever calculation you wanted in there. You could just as well create completely different tables with different content.

Comment: I can't for the life of me figure out what my issue is then. The data in my tables is independent of the filter on months as well, but as soon as I filter on a merged dependent detail variable object all the hidden tables suddenly appear. And that doesn't even address the issue of the independent filter on months seems to be filtering down my data when viewing singular months, as they aren't including data from the previous months.

Comment: I think I just figured it out. It's related to what you mentioned in your answer above. My merged dependent detail variable input control had dependencies set for the entire report body. When I switched it to just each of the 18 tables, it now works. The issue with cumulative months seems to have resolved itself too when I referenced the actual object itself, rather than a variable wrapping it.